# How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python for lines with multiple objects/functions in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, line-breaks, long-lines

With [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), the maximum line length should be 79 characters. I have a line like the following

```
object1.function1().function2().function3()
```

or

```
object1.object2.object3.function1()
```

which is more than 79 characters. How should I do a line break, in these cases?

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No need, there's not a problem with duplicates, they serve as markers to help other people find the answer :)